# Fallo en Coordinates

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en Python y estoy creando un escaner OCR  a través de una webcam el el siguiente fragmento de código

```
for i in range(100):
        if scores is None or final_score[i] > 0.5:
            count = count + 1
    print('count',count)
    printcount =0;

    for i in classes[0]:
        print(boxes[0])
        printcount = printcount +1
        if(category_index[i]['name']=="sign_readable"):
          #checkingSerial=True
          try:
              coordinates = vis_util.return_coordinates(
                        frame,
                        np.squeeze(boxes),
                        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                        np.squeeze(scores),
                        category_index,
                        use_normalized_coordinates=False,
                        line_thickness=8,
                        min_score_thresh=0.90)
          except:
              print("Failed to get coords")
          print(category_index[i]['name'])
          print(coordinates[0])
          print(i)
          it += 1
          if(it>10):
              it=0
```

me salta el error

```
line 174, in <module>
    print(coordinates[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

y me habeis indicado que el problema esta en el
`coordinates = vis_util.return_coordinates` como puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: tienes tu código bien indentado?

Comment: si, esta correctamente indentado, el problema esta en el codigo

Comment: Pies no parece, tu `if` esta varios espacios más y no tiene la misma sangría que tu `print`